# Python: Im building An Scroll bot which scroll one unit down when user says to scroll down

Tags: python, python-3.x

HI folks actually im looking for ideas, is it possible to scroll down/up through python on voice command. Need help, ik about selenium but it opens a browser for specific url, but im trying to do is that user is siting far away from mouse and wants to scroll down/up Then is there a way to directly scroll down/up on same browser instead of opening one? * please dont delete this i need ideas im completely blank right now *

Comment: You may want to read [ask].

Comment: robert the question focus on one topic only dont close it cause you dont know the solution or have expertise in it

Comment: I cannot close questions alone, I am not a moderator. I don't vote on questions when I'm unfamiliar with the technology. I did vote to close your question because IMHO it's too broad. You should always post what you've already tried and how that didn't work for you. That's why I suggested you read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could use [pyautogui](https://pypi.org/project/PyAutoGUI/) and a voice recognizer (I will use [pyttsx3](https://pypi.org/project/pyttsx3/), and [speech_recognition](https://pypi.org/project/SpeechRecognition/) for this

```
import speech_recognition as sr
import pyautogui


def listen():
    reconizer = sr.Recognizer()

    with sr.Microphone() as source:
        audio = r.listen(source)
    try:
        text = recognizer.recognize_google(audio)
        print(text)
        return text
    except:
        print("Could not recognize your voice")
        return "None"


while True:
    if 'scroll up' in listen():
        pyautogui.scroll(-1) # Note: This is scrolling up one click, to change it just change the -1 to something smaller
    if 'scroll down' in listen():
        pyautogui.scroll(1) # Note: This is scrolling down one click, to change it just change the 1 to something larger
```

Comment: thanks bro for help, but idk what is the bug with pyautogui scroll isnt working

Comment: @helpinghand What is not working? If it's the scroll function not working, you should try changing the 1 to something larger (type into a python terminal `import pyautogui` and then `pyautogui.scroll(10)`.